# WebGL Directional Lighting - Lighting a cube (lighting not working properly)

Tags: javascript

I have been rewriting this code a few times now, but the same problem with the lighting appears... I am comparing this code with the code I wrote a few months ago that does the same thing (lighting a cube) and it doesn't seem like I am missing anything.

Front and back side of the cube are okay, but the left and right sides are acting strangely, and also the top and the bottom... looks like there is a problem with the normals, but they are okay... checked them and rewrote them a few times just to be sure.

Example: http://gamedevelopment.t15.org/WebGL/WebGL%20Examples/Example%207%20-%20Ambient%20And%20Directional%20Light/

Shaders:

```
<script id="vShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
        attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;

        uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
        uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

        uniform vec3 uAmbientLightColor;

        uniform vec3 uDirectionalLightColor;
        uniform vec3 uLightDirection;

        uniform bool uUseLighting;

        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
        varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

        void main(void){
            gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
            vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;

            if(!uUseLighting){
                vLightWeighting = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            }else{
                vec3 transformedNormal = aVertexNormal * uNMatrix;
                float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(uLightDirection, transformedNormal), 0.0);
                vLightWeighting = uAmbientLightColor + uDirectionalLightColor * directionalLightWeighting;
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script id="fShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;

        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
        varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

        uniform sampler2D uSampler;

        void main(void){
            vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
            gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb * vLightWeighting, textureColor.a);
        }
    </script>
```

Code:

```
var gl;
function initGL(canvas){
    try{
        gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
        gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
        gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
    }catch(e){
        console.log("WebGL context was not initialized.");
        return null;
    }
}

function getShader(id, gl){
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
    if(!shaderScript){
        console.log(id + " - invalid shader id.");
    }

    var shaderString = "";
    var shaderChild = shaderScript.firstChild;
    while(shaderChild){
        if(shaderChild.nodeType == "3")
            shaderString += shaderChild.textContent;
        shaderChild = shaderChild.nextSibling;
    }

    var shader;
    if(shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex")
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    else if(shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment")
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    else{
        console.log(id + " - invalid shader id.");
        return null;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderString);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if(!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
        console.log(id + " error: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return null;
    }

    return shader;
}

var shaderProgram;
function initShaders(){
    var vShader = getShader("vShader", gl);
    var fShader = getShader("fShader", gl);

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if(!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)){
        console.log("Shader program was not linked.");
        return null;
    }

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

    shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);

    shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexNormal");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute);

    shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
    shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
    shaderProgram.nMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uNMatrix");
    shaderProgram.samplerUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler");
    shaderProgram.lightDirectionUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uLightDirection");
    shaderProgram.directionalLightColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uDirectionalLightColor");
    shaderProgram.ambientLightColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uAmbientLightColor");
    shaderProgram.useLightingUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uUseLighting");
}

var cubeVertexPositionBuffer, cubeVertexIndexBuffer, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer, cubeVertexNormalBuffer;
function initBuffers(){
    // Cube.
    cubeVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    vertices = [
        // Front face.
        -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,

        // Back face.
        -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

        // Left face.
        -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

        // Right face.
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

        // Top face.
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,

        // Bottom face.
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0
    ]
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    cubeVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    cubeVertexPositionBuffer.rotAngle = 0;

    cubeVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    var indices = [
        0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,
        4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7,
        8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11,
        12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15,
        16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19,
        20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23
    ];

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexIndexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    cubeVertexIndexBuffer.numItems = 36;

    cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    textureCoords = [
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,

        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,

        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,

        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,

        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,

        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0
    ];
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize = 2;

    cubeVertexNormalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    var normals = [
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,

        0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, -1.0,

        -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,

        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,

        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,

        0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    ]
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexNormalBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(normals), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    cubeVertexNormalBuffer.itemSize = 3;
}

var pMatrix = mat4.create();
var mvMatrixStack = [];
var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
var nMatrix = mat3.create();
function setMatrixUniforms(){
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
    mat3.normalFromMat4(nMatrix, mvMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(shaderProgram.nMatrixUniform, false, nMatrix);
}

function mvPushMatrix(){
    var copy = mat4.create();
    mat4.copy(copy, mvMatrix);
    mvMatrixStack.push(copy);
}

function mvPopMatrix(){
    mvMatrix = mvMatrixStack.pop();
}

function drawScene(){
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mat4.perspective(pMatrix, 45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0);
    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

    // Draw cube.
    mvPushMatrix();

    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, -7.0]);
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, degToRad(cubeVertexPositionBuffer.rotAngle), [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, cubeVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexNormalBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute, cubeVertexNormalBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, cubeTexture);
    gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);

    // Lighting.
    gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.useLightingUniform, true);
    gl.uniform3f(shaderProgram.ambientLightColorUniform, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
    gl.uniform3f(shaderProgram.directionalLightColorUniform, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
    var lightingDirection = [0.0, 0.0, -1.0];
    var adjustedLD = vec3.create();
    vec3.normalize(adjustedLD, lightingDirection);
    vec3.scale(adjustedLD, adjustedLD, -1);
    gl.uniform3fv(shaderProgram.lightDirectionUniform, adjustedLD);

    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, cubeVertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    mvPopMatrix();
}

var lastTime = 0;
function animate(){
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();

    if(lastTime != 0){
        var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;

        if(cubeVertexPositionBuffer.rotAngle > 360) cubeVertexPositionBuffer.rotAngle = 0;
        cubeVertexPositionBuffer.rotAngle += 45 * elapsed / 1000;
    }
    lastTime = timeNow;
}

function tick(){
    animate();
    drawScene();
    requestAnimFrame(tick);
}

function degToRad(degrees){
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

var cubeTexture;
function initTextures(){
    cubeTexture = gl.createTexture();
    cubeTexture.image = new Image();
    cubeTexture.image.onload = function(){
        handleLoadedTexture(cubeTexture);
    }
    cubeTexture.image.src = "textures/cube.png";
}

function handleLoadedTexture(texture){
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

function webGLStart(){
    initGL(document.getElementById("glCanvas"));
    initShaders();
    initBuffers();
    initTextures();

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    tick();
}
```

Lighting code is: references in initShaders(), normal and vertex buffers in initBuffers() and setting uniform variables in drawScene(), also creating normalMatrix in setMatrixUniforms().

I would be thankful if someone took their time to take a look at it and tell me what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. got angry and rewrote code once again, then little by little replaced code with some code from a working example... guys tell me! The problem is in the vertex shader and please tell me the difference between

```
vec3 transformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
```

and

```
vec3 transformedNormal = aVertexNormal * uNMatrix;
```

... the second one creates the bug, but it makes no sense... what does it matter the order in which i multiply.

Comment: Read up on [Matrix Multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication). You can compare you're two examples as saying "5 - 3 = 2" and "5 - 2 = -2". The order is important, if you want to get the desired result!